# Logic issue with breaking up string

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with the code necessary for this. My input for a string is for example denver/tulsa/dallas/, I want to be able to return denver/tulsa and tulsa/dallas . My original plan was to count the slashes, copy the string until its hits two slashes, which would give me denver/tulsa. But I dont know after going through the first time, how to start at t in tulsa for the next iteration.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Why not just split she string into at the `/` and then return 0/1, 1/2, 2/3, etc if there's more parts.

Answer (score 5):

> I dont know after going through the first time, how to start at t in tulsa for the next iteration.

Don't.

Instead, split the string into *tokens* (each delimited by a slash; here you have three).

Then, once you have a list of "denver", "tulsa" and "dallas", output your combinations using simple integer arithmetic and array indexes (element 0 & 1, then element 1 & 2, then element 2 & 3, then element 3 & 4, then element 4 & 5…).

As always, break your problem into *steps* or *pieces* before proceeding.

You *could* do it your way (and it would be more memory-efficient to do so), but you'd have to keep track of how long each substring was, using lots of variables, and it would be quite messy/hard to follow.

Comment: I was trying to be as efficent as possible since Im working with custom vector,string,linkedlist classes, but I broke it up to now instead of the above I have a vector of Denver Tulsa Dallas * Denver Dallas *, (using the * as a breakpoint). But im still trying to figure out how to increment it to concatonate the correct two strings

Comment: @zavier: Save yourself a world of trouble and get a vector of Denver, Tulsa, Dallas. Three elements. That's it. It really need not be any more complicated than that. You're still trying to do multiple parts of your algorithm simultaneously, and that's why you're getting confused. Make it so that you have a simple container with the three words you need to operate one, then it's just a basic matter of _counting_. If you still want a more memory-efficient version after that, _then_ adapt your simple solution. But not before.

Comment: okay got it, thanks for the help @Lightness Races in Orbit, now I got it working now on the rest of the project, awesome username btw